# How to compile SR language under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

What compiler should be installed in order to compile SR (Synchronizing Resources) Language?
Or is this language still in use?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be actively maintained.  However you might have some luck using gcc to build it.

Comment: gcc gave me 
/usr/bin/ld:hello.sr: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:hello.sr:1: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status